# Undefined reference with existing .gnu.lto_ symbols in static linking? (cairo, mingw)

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw, static-linking, undefined-reference

A project I'm working on builds `cairo` from source, calling its `./configure` and `make`. I'm using `git-bash.exe` from a PortableGit install, with environment variables from a different MinGW. So I have:

```
WORKGROUP+user@AD-X MINGW32 /z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo (master)
$ which gcc
//WORKGROUP.EX.COM/Users/user/Downloads/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.3-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev1/mingw32/bin/gcc

WORKGROUP+user@AD-X MINGW32 /z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo (master)
$ gcc --version | head -1
gcc.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.3
```

The compilation goes fine, but linking goes bad here:

```
[...]
  CC     any2ppm-any2ppm.o
  CCLD   any2ppm.exe
C:\Users\TEMPCR~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\45\ccaKwhAD.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `cairo_image_surface_create'
C:\Users\TEMPCR~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\45\ccaKwhAD.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `cairo_image_surface_get_data'
[...]
makefile:483: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

 ^ Received error ^
```

Unfortunately, `make V=1` does not work for this Makefile to reveal its commands, so I used a dry run `make -n` to get the `CCLD any2ppm.exe` command, which is:

```
echo "  CCLD  " any2ppm.exe;Z:/user/Downloads/PortableGit/usr/bin/sh.exe ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc     -Os -m32  -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -m32 -o any2ppm.exe any2ppm-any2ppm.o ../util/cairo-script/libcairo-script-interpreter.la ../src/libcairo.la      -lm
```

... and by removing the `--silent` switch from the `../libtool` and re-running the command, the actual `gcc` command failing is (line split mine):

```
# runs in /z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo/test
libtool: link: gcc \
-Os -m32 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -m32 \
-o .libs/any2ppm.exe any2ppm-any2ppm.o \
../util/cairo-script/.libs/libcairo-script-interpreter.a \
Z:/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo/src/.libs/libcairo.a \
-LZ:/user/Downloads/path/to/build/_buildroot/lib ../src/.libs/libcairo.a \
/z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/_buildroot/lib/libpixman-1.a \
/z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/_buildroot/lib/libpng16.a \
-lgdi32 -lmsimg32 -lz -pthread
```

Here's the thing - the link error has "`undefined reference to`cairo_image_surface_get_data'`", but if I check:

```
WORKGROUP+user@AD-X MINGW32 /z/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo/test (master)
$ nm -a Z:/user/Downloads/path/to/build/cairo/src/.libs/libcairo.a  | grep cairo_image_surface_get_data
00000000 r .gnu.lto_cairo_image_surface_get_data.f85122d4
```

... there *is* some sort of a symbol, except prefixed with `.gnu.lto_`? I've found [Sourceware Bugzilla: 13557 – Undef. ref. err. when linking with slim LTO obj. in static lib. (mingw32 target)](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13557), but I guess that fix is already in the compiler I use (4.9.3)? I also tried reversing the order of the libraries included on the linking command line, that didn't work either.

So, in brief, in `libcairo.a` which is explicitly given with correct full path at the `gcc` command line (and statically linked), there is a `.gnu.lto_cairo_image_surface_get_data.f85122d4`, yet linking fails with "`` undefined reference to `cairo_image_surface_get_data' ``". Why does this happen, and how can I get the link command to succeed?

(Ironically, I have compiled cairo before in the same `git-bash.exe` on the same machine, but it was probably a different MinGW environment - cannot really recall)

Answer (score 0):

Found this: [undefined reference cross compiling static libraries with LTO under GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372667/undefined-reference-cross-compiling-static-libraries-with-lto-under-gcc)

> I'm able to reproduce this linking problem on Mingw32-gcc 4.9.2 under Win7 64-bit. However, I did get it to link successfully by adding -ffat-lto-objects as a workaround:

... and it worked for me, too...